# TabBar Application with a View that has a UIButton on the View to goto another View outside the TabBar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to iPhone development, and multiple views (xib or nib) are really confusing me. This is what i'm trying to achieve...

using TabBarControllerAppDelegate

Have 5 different TabBar Items and have created 5 different Views thru the TabBarController

The First View has a UIButton that is a Next button that needs to go to another view called View2.XIB.

I setup a new UIViewController which references the View2 and an IBAction for the switchPage, etc but not able to get it to do anything when clicking on the button.

All of My TabBar buttons work but not able to Navigate to anything outside of the Tabbar

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Anyone have any examples

Answer (score 2):

- IBAction switchPageButtonPressed:(id)sender

{

[self.tabbarcontroller.tabBar setSelectedItem:[self.tabbarcontroller.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]];

here 1 means ur 2nd tabbar

}

Comment: I get error as `'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'`

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to find the problem without the code, but I will assume your action code for the switchPage button is incorrect.  You should use code similar to the following:

```
- IBAction switchPageButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    ViewController2 *view2VC = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];     
    [self presentModalViewController:nview2VC animated:YES];
    [view2VC release];
}
```

If you are confident your method works, then you will want to verify that the action is hooked up correctly.  The easiest way to do this is to place a breakpoint on the method and run the app in Debug.  When you click the button, the debugger should break on your method, if it doesn't, you will need to check your connections in Interface Builder.